# Responsive web design - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This may be so basic but I like to be certain about this.

I am using bootstrap for my frontend. But after testing my page, it realize it is not responsive in a way since some of the elements are flying else where when I reduce the size of my browser.

I thought bootstrap `automatically` makes the web page responsive. Do I have to use standard class name for my forms to make it accurately responsive?

**PS:** Learning how to make web pages responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn to use the bootstrap grid system. Bootstrap does not make it responsive on its own.

check out these links:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Comment: what if i decide to use `lg` which is large  desktop and laptops, how do i cater for phones and tablets ?

Comment: use `sm` and `xs` for tablets and phones.

Comment: as media queries?

Comment: You can use all three at the same time like this `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 ">`

Comment: Oh okay i see..so when do you use media queries?

Comment: We usually don't need to use media queries with bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap provides **tools** that will help you in responsive website design. It is not, on and of its own, a magic wand that will transform your design.

You need to rely on the arsenal that is the Bootstrap toolkit like Grid and the ability to specific different column widths by breakpoint; by utilizing options for showing and hiding content based on screen dimensions, or wrappers for making tables responsive, etc, etc.

Comment: Okay :) . So in this case, i have to use media queries to correct the elements into right position for all screen sizes?

Comment: That depends on your design and how well it aligns with Bootstraps CSS.  You MIGHT need custom media queries, or it could be as simple as adding additional grid breakpoints / hiding & showing content as mentioned above.  You really should check out Bootstraps documentation per the suggestion of another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is not enough just to load bootstrap on the page. That way page would not become responsive.

Bootstrap is a framework for building responsive websites/apps, and you should organize your code following Bootstrap instructions and use already predefined class names from Bootstrap.

Of course you can override that default classes but this is another thing.

Good place to start is:
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/

Comment: Sure i overrode  the classes in my case. so i have to use media queries to get my elements into place?

Answer (score 0):

you need to read bootstrap screen resolution funtion
how to create screen resolution class for size.
Suppose if screen size is 5000px then use this class 
orif screen size is 1000px then use this class.

Comment: To me, your answer is ok, but you should provide him/her an example with `@media` rules